# 3d visualize tools in WPF

Tags: visualization, wpftoolkit, surface, 3d-modelling, helix-3d-toolkit

I am getting the surface shown in the picture that i am attaching below ,I want triangle with the same color and texture Could you please guide me on the same. 
and one more thing ,This is because the triangles are not oriented consistently which only makes sense if the output is a true oriented surface without any artifact.if any one suggest me which visualization tool where it shows the triangles without considering orientation in WPF, i have used helix toolkit in WPF but it gives same result this is 3d model:

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

You can either try to fix the orientation of the triangles or define the `BackMaterial` of your `GeometryModel3D` to be the same as the `Material`.

Comment: I have no idea about how to fix the orientation of triangles if you have please guide me on same,i already tried to apply BackMaterial or Material is same but still i got same result.

Comment: Well, to suggest any improvement, I guess at least you would have to show the code creating the triangles as it is done now...

Comment: I have used crust algorithm of Point Tool toolbox which is made in MATLAB. This is the link for this code https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41123-pointtool?focused=3781873&tab=function